# How to auto layout Scroll View fit with content View inside it?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I want to build post-comment interface like facebook. In storyboard scene, the `superView` has 2 parts (Content View and Comment Section). Content View contains the `scrollView` which has all of the elements inside it, include the `tableView` which shows user comments. My problem is that i dont know how to auto layout scrollView to fit with it's content inside. Please show me how to do ? Thank for your helping !!!

[image]

Comment: Best way is to use single tableview with different kind of cells

Comment: Nesting is not proper way!!

Comment: Your `content view` -> `Cell1` and `comment` -> `cell2`

Answer (score 1):

one of the ways you use is making outlet for height constraint of container view in Controller swift file
and update it by calculating your post height+number of comments shown * height of comment.

Comment: i have the problem with the dynamic cell. If the cell is estimate row height (=66), everything fine but when the cell is dynamic (with the long comment), scroll view doesn't show enough content. Please help me how to deal with ? Thank you